# Is it possible to turn a 3d animation into 2d lineart?

Tags: 2d

I made a very simple city with just a bunch of tall rectangles and animated the camera panning through it. I want to use the animation in a 2d animation but the "3d-ness" of the city makes it look really weird. Is it possible to automatically outline all the buildings and turn the image black and white?

Answer (score 0):

The outlining can be done by using "Freestyle" (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/introduction.html) in your rendering.

For the black and white look of the buildings, you can either use postprocessing in the compositor (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/rgb_to_bw.html) or try giving the materials a "toon" shader (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/toon.html)